# What is the correct way to communicate variables through nested functions in Godot?

Tags: godot

- I have functions a, b, and c.
- a calls b in 100 times.
- b calls c 100 times.
- Therefore if a is called once, c is called 10,000 times.
- c requires many variables from a's scope.

Should I:

1. Pass the variables through b and c as parameters.
2. Define b and c in a's scope so they can access a's variables.
3. Define b in a's scope and define c in b's scope.
4. Make the variables member variables in the file that a is defined it, and change them from inside a.
5. Do some other thing.

I don't want to do 1 because then b and c will have *many* parameters. I don't want to do 2 or 3 because then b and c will be unnecessarily re-defined every time a is called. I don't want to do 4 because having member variables that are only used in a single place in a lower scope seems bad. Is there another option? Are any of my reasons not to do 1-4 wrong?

Comment: Is this GDScript? What do you mean by define a function in the scope of another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to do 4 (Make the variables member variables in the file that a is defined it, and change them from inside a).

> I don't want to do 4 because having member variables that are only used in a single place in a lower scope seems bad.

Make a new class for it.

---

If you start with 1 (Pass the variables through b and c as parameters).

You would have to solve the many parameters problem you describe:

> I don't want to do 1 because then b and c will have many parameters

To do so, you can define a new class to hold them, so you can pass a single parameter, which is a object of that new class. Once you have a new class, and given it is only used from the function a... Then it makes sense to make the function a into a member of the new class… If you do the same for the other functions, then you don't need to pass parameters at all, and you effectively have solution 4.

---

*I'm not sure about 2 and 3. Lambda functions are an upcoming feature in Godot 4.0 ([see](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/issues/2431)), which is not out yet. Are you using a custom build with that or… What?*

Comment: I'm not on a custom build; I just didn't realize defining a function inside another function isn't possible, or at least not as straightforward as it is in Python. My bad.